# How can I work with decimals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, decimal, currency

For the last hour I've tried several different solutions but none have solved my problem.

I have various input fields containing a decimal number (price of product) e.g. `98.00`.

Looping through a list of items, I need to add the fields together:

```
  // Calculate sub-total
  $('.selected_list li.order_line:visible').each(function(){
    var item_cost = $(this).find('input.item_cost').val();
    sub_total = sub_total + item_cost;
  })
```

How can I add these items and get a result containing two decimals?
My fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EgGUm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parseFloat:

```
 var item_cost = parseFloat($(this).find('input.item_cost').val());
```

More, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp)

Comment: Also you have an error and you get the value from the first input box on your jsfiddle. Resulting in adding the same value.

Comment: It's a fundamental function in javascript. It explains what you need to do. Simple.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/EgGUm/5/ Also, I think i removes trailing zeros.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/EgGUm/7/ .If you want to add every element in .p1 class then you will need to loop your .p1 values and add them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseFloat()` to convert the strings. I have updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EgGUm/11/

```
  // Calculate sub-total
  $('.selected_list li.order_line:visible').each(function(){
    var item_cost = parseFloat($(this).find('input.item_cost').val());
    sub_total = sub_total + item_cost;
  })
```

Comment: Did a little update, changed the a class name to add the right terms. http://jsfiddle.net/AzE65/